# Print on a variable height paper using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, printing, grid

I want to print bill on a roll paper using vb.net.
The requirements are as follows:
The width of the page is 300 pixels or 3 inches.
The height of the page is variable, depending on the number of the rows in the datagrid.
The page header will have an image.
The names of the items could be long, so they should not be chopped, rather print on the next line.

How should I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Get your Image height and  **xRows** (dgv.rows.count) *** Rowheight** 
So you have an Dynamic height.

Additional you could count string lengtht of your long Values and add for longer datarows the addidtional height

But that is just my idea.
Im sure there are better solutions

Comment: I took the height as (sum of (Height of Header Section) + (Sum of heights of all rows through iteration)).